# Sklearn error, cannot import name 'Logger' from 'joblib'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I am having problems with `scikit-learn` as everytime I try using the `GradientBoostingRegressor` class, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rober\Desktop\Privat\Roland_Manu_ProjektBeidl\numerai_datasets\testitest.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

  File "C:\Users\rober\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from .base import clone

  File "C:\Users\rober\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT

  File "C:\Users\rober\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import _joblib

  File "C:\Users\rober\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_joblib.py", line 8, in <module>
    from joblib import logger

ImportError: cannot import name 'logger' from 'joblib' (unknown location)
```

My code looks as follows

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

model = GradientBoostingRegressor(learning_rate=0.01, n_estimators=100,
                                      max_depth=5, validation_fraction=0.2, n_iter_no_change=10,
                                      tol=1e-3)
```

Can someone please help me? I have tried loading the external `joblib` library, but to no success.

EDIT: Sorry, the whole error log is shown now.

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? `import sklearn;print(sklearn.__version__)`

Comment: It would help if you showed us the entire error traceback message instead of just the final line.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it. This is the whole message that I get.

Comment: Also, I am using version 0.23.2. I've read that the scikit joblib library was removed and that just using the normal joblib library works, but this did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-installing sklearn by using Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
```